# Bootbox Modal call not working in prepend function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am prepending a `<td>` to my `table` in my jQuery code and in the prepended `<td>` I have a `<a>` link with class `confirmDelete`.

Any clicked item with the class `confirmDelete` attached to it will call and open the modal. Only the newly appended list item with `<a>` will not open modal.

This is what I have in the prepend:

```
<tr><td align="center" class="number"></td><td>'+jsonStr.departmentName+'</td><td>'+jsonStr.departmentDateAdded+'</td><td>'+jsonStr.departmentAddedBy+'</td><td class="linkAction"><a href=""><i class="glyphicon2 glyphicon-edit"></i></a> | <a class="confirmDelete" id="'+jsonStr.departmentID+'"><i class="glyphicon2 glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td></tr>
```

Here is the `.confirmDelete` function

```
$('.confirmDelete').on('click', function() {
  var ID = $(this).attr('id');
  var departmentName = $(".departmentNameValue" + ID).val();

  bootbox.dialog({
    message: "Are you sure you want to delete following: <br>Department Name:<b> " + departmentName + "</b>",
    title: "<i class='glyphicon2 glyphicon-trash'></i> Delete",
    buttons: {
      success: {
        label: "No",
        className: "btn-success",
        callback: function() {
          $('.bootbox').modal('hide');
        }
      },
      danger: {
        label: "Delete",
        className: "btn-danger",
        callback: function() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "deleteDepartment.php",
            data: 'ID=' + ID,
            success: function(msg) {
              if (msg == "departmentDeleted") {
                $("#" + ID).fadeOut();
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

Any ideas on how to get the class to attach to the newly prepended item?

Answer (score 0):

The important thing here is **when** you prepend the `confirmDelete` buttons.

Binding events onto elements, as you do with `$('.confirmDelete').on('click')`, only affects the elements which are **already** in the DOM. It means if you add anything in the DOM after `$('.confirmDelete').on('click')` binding, they wont be binded.

If you want to bind some events, to those elements which may already be in the DOM or may be in the DOM in the future, you should use the proper event binding method which is up to your jQuery version:

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

So if your jQuery version is 1.7+, you should replace your binding code with this:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.confirmDelete' , function() {

// handler function

} );
```